# IndexOutOfBoundsException: I don't see in my while loop

Tags: java, arraylist, while-loop, indexoutofboundsexception

Ive been stuck on this `IndexOutOfBoundsException` that I can't figure out and I don't see why it's pointing to my `while` loop. Any suggestions on what to do? The method btw is a round robin scheduling simulator, it seems to be working perfectly with one of my testfiles but not the other.

```
public void roundRobin2(ArrayList<Jobs> c, int startSize)
{   
    //int n = 0;
    double counter = 0;
    double compTime = 0;
    while(!c.isEmpty())
    {
        int i = 0;
        System.out.println(c);
        for(i = 0; i < c.size(); i++)
        {
            if((c.get(i).jobTime) >= 2)
            {
                c.get(i).jobTime -= 2;
                counter += 2;

                if((c.get(i).jobTime) == 0)
                {
                    compTime += counter;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                (c.get(i).jobTime) -= 1;        
                counter += 1;

                if((c.get(i).jobTime) == 0)
                {
                    compTime += counter;
                }
            }
            //System.out.print("-" + c.get(i).jobName + "-" + counter);
            //n++;
            //if(n%10 == 0)
            //{
                //System.out.println("\n");
            //}
        }
        for(i = 0; i < c.size(); i++)
        {
            while(!c.isEmpty() && (c.get(i).jobTime) == 0)
            {
                c.remove(i);
            }       
        }
    }
    System.out.println("\n\nAverage completion times: "+ compTime + "/" + startSize +" = " + ((compTime)/startSize));
}
```

The exception stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 7, Size: 7
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
    at cs431.edu.cpp.Main.roundRobin2(Main.java:143)
```

Comment: It will be much easier if you share the input that causes the error

Comment: @bumpy I don't think so. When you have this kind of error, only the line of the out of bounds access is important. Then, you track all what happens to the variable(s) used to compute the index that was out of bound and figure out why it was invalid. It has Nothing to do with the input if everything is expressed in terms of `Collection.size()` instead of integer litterals

Comment: @Dici How can you track what happens to the variables if you don't know what the input is? By input I mean the jobs in the ArrayList.

Comment: Only the index is important, and the bound conditions in the loops, that's what I mean

Comment: Sorry for removing your edited text, but it doesn't into a question of a Q&A style side like Stack Overflow. You can show your satisfaction by accepting the correct answer and by upvoting good answers (if you have the necessary amount of reputation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code:

```
while(!c.isEmpty() && (c.get(i).jobTime) == 0)
{
    c.remove(i);
}
```

will fail if `i` is removing the last element, but not causing the list to go empty. Use this instead:

```
while (i < c.size() && c.get(i).jobTime == 0)
{
    c.remove(i);
}
```

**Update**

Your code would clean up a lot by using the `for (obj : list)` loop, and you should remove elements using an `Iterator`. Here's the cleaned up code:

```
public static void roundRobin2(ArrayList<Jobs> c, int startSize)
{
    double counter = 0;
    double compTime = 0;
    while (! c.isEmpty())
    {
        System.out.println(c);
        for (Jobs jobs : c)
        {
            if (jobs.jobTime >= 2)
            {
                jobs.jobTime -= 2;
                counter += 2;
            }
            else
            {
                jobs.jobTime -= 1;
                counter += 1;
            }
            if (jobs.jobTime == 0)
            {
                compTime += counter;
            }
        }
        for (Iterator<Jobs> jobsIter = c.iterator(); jobsIter.hasNext(); )
        {
            Jobs jobs = jobsIter.next();
            if (jobs.jobTime == 0)
            {
                jobsIter.remove();
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("\n\nAverage completion times: " + compTime + "/" + startSize + " = " + (compTime / startSize));
}
```

Comment: It won't fail this way, but you are giving the OP the advice to keep his code which inherently bad . A good answer should disapprove the removal of items in a loop over the collection.

Comment: Thank Andreas this worked, and like I said its removing during the iterations because that what i want it to do as soon as the job is done i want it out

Comment: @Dici Yeah, I wanted to clean up his code too, so I just did, but my answer was exactly correct, as it answer his question. Nothing more, but it was a very valid answer, and in no way an advice on anything else.

Comment: @user3646746 check my answer, it is more efficient and more elegant

Comment: @Andreas my personal philosophy is to give the best possible answer, not just a working solution. To me this was a case of an XY problem. A XY problem is when someone asks `How do I get the three last letters of the name of a file ?`. If you ask the person what they are trying to do, they tell you `I'm trying to get the extension of the file`. An extension is not always 3 characters long, so the approach of the OP is wrong and you should propose a better approach instead of answering directly the question the way it was asked

Comment: @Dici That is your personal philosophy, and I applaud that, and you should do that in your own answer, but please don't down-vote, which means "This answer is not useful", when the answer is a valid direct answer to the question.

Comment: @Andreas it was to encourage an edit... I still don't agree with your answer but I'll remove the downvote since you're willing to help

Comment: @Dici Thank you, and please keep up the good work on providing better answer, but the person asking the question may not care for that (other readers might), so please don't discourage *simple* answers by down-voting them, as long as they are "correct", of course. ;-)

Comment: @Andreas not convinced ! If you want to see better code in the world it starts there :D Anyway, peace !

Answer (score 1):

You are removing items in a collection you are iterating through at the same time, this is very bad and you should never do that. You can do so using an `Iterator` which has a `remove` method (however this is rarely efficient), or make a temporary copy of your collection. By the way round-robin can be implemented much more easily.

This solution uses a `LinkedList` because removal at the head and insertion at the end are both `O(1)`, this is efficient and safe. I also compressed some of your logic as a bonus :

```
public void roundRobin2(List<Jobs> jobs, int startSize) {
    double counter = 0;
    double compTime = 0;

    Deque<Jobs> uncompletedJobs = new LinkedList<>(jobs);
    while (!uncompletedJobs.isEmpty()) {
        Job job = uncompletedJobs.pop();
        int taskTime = job.jobTime >= 2 ? 2 : 1;
        job.jobTime -= taskTime;
        counter += taskTime;
        if (job.jobTime == 0) {
            compTime += counter;
        } else {
             uncompletedJobs.addLast(job);
        }
    }
    jobs.clear();
    System.out.println("\n\nAverage completion times: "+ compTime + "/" + startSize +" = " + ((compTime)/startSize));
}
```

Comment: I would like to propose you a better implementation but I don't entirely understand your intention. Why do you need to remove items from the collection ?

Comment: I agree it generally shouldn't be done, but I don't think this is the problem in this specific case because he uses a for loop, and `c.size()` is reevaluated each time.

Comment: Not in the while at the end of the method

Comment: @dici well the only reason im removing is b/c once the job is done i want it out of the process

Comment: Ok, I'm gonna propose you something

Comment: @Dici If you want to provide a better algorithm for doing so, this is great, but you should be sticking to the code format of the original question, because that might be required, e.g. the mandatory use of {braces} on separate lines.

Comment: @Andreas I guess if my algorithm is correct the OP can reformat it against his taste ^^ But fine, i'll fix that

Comment: I totally understood dici algorithm but i would like to sick to mine and i understand the one andreas wrote even more, but one question, the iterator where does it remove the job from? @Andreas

Comment: This answer is like "I want to write my own code!*. Absolutely not related to the OP's problem.

Comment: @user3646746 your algorithm is `O(n^2)`, which is extremely slow (slower than a sort !). My solution is `O(n)`.

Comment: @user3646746 The `Iterator.remove()` method removes the last element that was retrieved by `next()`.

Comment: @Dici I don't think you're right on that. The original code does a little extra work by have nested loops and not merging the two inner loops, while your code merged the inner loops and uses a queue for continuous processing, but the original code is hardly exponential in performance.

Comment: @Andreas the complexity of a code is not the number of loops. In a list, calling `remove` is in average `O(n)`  because it requires to iterate over the list if is a linked list and to shift the elements if it is an array list. As you can see, a loop containing a `remove` is `O(n^2)`. At the contrary, my code has a single loop performing two operations : a removal at the head, and an insertion at the end. A `LinkedList` provides constant time access to both of its ends so none of these operations require to traverse the list. Therefore, the overall complexity is `O(n)`

Comment: @Andreas it is surely not exponential, it is polynomial, like mine, but polynomial of degree 2 (square) whereras mine is degree one (linear)

Comment: @Dici Agreed, *if* it is a `LinkedList`, but the code is explicitly an `ArrayList`, and `Iterator.remove()` and `ArrayList.remove(i)` will have the exact same performance. Actually, `Iterator.remove()` calls `ArrayList.remove(i)`, if you look at the implementation!

Comment: @Andreas same for an array list, look at my comment. For the array list, you need to shift all the items at the right of the removed item

Comment: @Dici Sorry, I get your point now. By using a linked list as the queue and the "move to the end of queue" logic using pop/addLast, the cost of removing an element is O(1), at the slight up-front cost of copying the list. Thumbs up! (or rather vote up).